# Php emailer on page not working

Tags: php, html, email

any reason I couldn't embed this on a page? It doesn't run or render the rest of the page...

```
<?php
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); 
mail('dotedo@txt.att.net', 'Private Gallery', $ip);
?>
```

Comment: Not rendering the rest of the page (a "white screen of death") means "go look in your error log" for a detailed error message. Always in development, turn up error reporting and display errors on screen: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Do you get an error?  If the script halts execution entirely then that sounds like there's an error being reported somewhere in the logs.

Comment: If you are trying to run that on PHP < 5.3, it will have syntax errors since the shortened ternary `?:` isn't supported.

Comment: `if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){ echo 'good';}else{echo 'bad'}` to help narrow the problem

Comment: The binary `?:` operator requires at least PHP 5.3 on the server.